# using cpan with 2 installed perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 perl installed

```
/usr/bin/perl
```

and

```
/usr/local/perls/perl-5.16.2/bin/perl
```

I am using

```
cpan -i Compress::Zlib installs
```

to install perl modules

What to do to have perl modules installed for `/usr/local/perls/perl-5.16.2/bin/perl` (using `cpan -i`) since by default *cpan -i* installs perl modules in `/usr/bin/perl` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install modules for your v5.16.2, use

```
/usr/local/perls/perl-5.16.2/bin/cpan
```

Comment: @user1806799 just a little additional advice in case you want to use the /usr/local perl most of the time: you could add its path to the PATH env variabe or put it in front of the current perl path in order to have a higher priority